Natural Deduction: Using disjunctive syllogism with a negation in the disjunction.
Since I have found nothing online about it, does disjunctive syllogism still work in natural deduction if we have a negation on one side of the disjunction and infer the double negation to prove the other side.

I appreciate any help

Usually it is not a primitive rule of ND, but your proof works using Disjunction Elimination.

It all depends on how Disjunctive Syllogism is defined in your particular proof system. Some systems may allow what you do just fine. Others will insist you first double negate the Q. And others don;t have Disjunctive Syllogism as a rule at all.

$P\vee\neg Q, Q\vdash P$ is a valid inference using the derived rule of Disjunctive Syllogism.
Although, if you are using an online proof checker (such as https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/), then the system may be finicky and object.
If so, you may derive the double negative to enable DS, or go back to the fundamentals:
$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\qquad\raise{2ex}{\fitch{~~1.~~P\vee\neg Q\\~~2.~~\neg R\to Q}{\fitch{~~3.~~\neg R}{\fitch{~~4.~~\neg Q}{~~5.~~Q\hspace{6ex}{\to}\mathrm E~2,3\\~~6.~~\bot\hspace{7ex}\neg\mathrm E~5,6}\\~~7.~~\neg\neg Q\hspace{7ex}\neg\mathrm I~4{-}6\\~~8.~~P\hspace{10ex}{\rm DS}~1,7}\\~~~~\vdots}}\quad\fitch{~~1.~~P\vee\neg Q\\~~2.~~\neg R\to Q}{\fitch{~~3.~~\neg R}{\fitch{~~4.~~P}{}\\\fitch{~~5.~~\neg Q}{~~6.~~Q\hspace{6ex}{\to}\mathrm E~2,3\\~~7.~~\bot\hspace{7ex}\neg\mathrm E~5,6\\~~8.~~P\hspace{7ex}\mathrm X~7}\\~~9.~~P\hspace{10ex}{\vee}\mathrm E~1,4{-}4,5{-}8}\\~~~~\vdots}$
